# Unable to console logs from safari using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am trying to get console logs of safari using selenium webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
d = DesiredCapabilities.SAFARI
d['logginfPrefs']={'browser':'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Safari(desired_capabilities=d)
driver.get("test.com")
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Your Name (Required)']").send_keys("test")
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print entry
time.sleep(10)
```

But getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Fuzebox_6/PycharmProjects/Codechef/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1053, in get_log
    return self.execute(Command.GET_LOG, {'type': log_type})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The command 'POST /session/3A5DB2BA-CE01-4D7C-895E-32F1C3381F7A/log' is not implemented.
```

Can some one please tell me what are the flags needed to get console logs

Comment: SafariDriver is now made by apple itself. It doesn't support log command. So you can't do anything about that

Comment: A possbile reason is Safari WebDriver not implement this feature, you can use the same code but change to Chrome browser, if work,  means script has no code issue. issue from Safari WebDriver.